# Migrating TFS 2012 server installation to a new server

Tags: tfs

We are moving our installation from a hosted server to a VM on our local network.  We have a mix of local users and Domain users.  I am concerned about the local users that were created on the existing server.  What will happen to them in the new environment?

For example

Server1\JohnDoe will not exist on the new server.  What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are effectively doing is a domain change from the perspective of TFS. You need to merge two procedures. First is the environment move:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883.aspx

And the second is the hardware move:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx

What you are doing is both at once. This can be done safely and you need to be very careful with the accounts issue.

I have done this a whole bunch and documented it:

http://nakedalm.com/in-place-upgrade-of-tfs-2008-to-tfs-2010-with-move-to-new-domain/

Thats for an older version but the principals are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The domain will be the same.  Does that mean I can skip the environment move?

Comment: The domain will not be the same if you are moving from server1\username to domain\username. That is also a domain move...